# angular coverts http network calls to https

Tags: angular, observable, thermal-printer, pos

I am trying ng-thermal-print module in angular. Angular converts http printer url to https that is why it gives connection time error.

[image]

Comment: http gets automatically converted to https

Answer (score 0):

Use `localhost` instead of 192.168.1.60 / your "real ip". This http -> https might happen because of this.

A related Stack Overflow answer states:

> When you access localhost, your /etc/hosts file will tell your computer not to look any further and redirects you to your own computer. When you access the local IP adress, your computer will ask the router to fetch the data, and your router will then point back to your computer.